Implementing """" from formula into VBA
I have excel formula
=IFERROR(MID(M4;FIND("""";M4)+1;LEN(M4)-FIND("""";M4)-1);"-")

Now I want to implement this in VBA to enter this formula and automatically drop it down.
I've started with code like below
  wsFinal.Range("P2").Formula = "=IFERROR(MID(N4;FIND("""";N4)+1;LEN(N4)-FIND("""";N4)-1);"" - "")"
    wsFinal.Range("P2").Autofill Destination:=wsFinal.Range("P2" & ":P" & lastRowRange), Type:=xlFillDefault

Unfortunatelly, I with """" I receive error type mismatch.
How to solve such challenge in code?

You can use =CHR(34) instead of "".

Formula property requires commas as argument separators.

Nothing wrong with "=IFERROR(MID(N4;FIND("""";N4)+1;LEN(N4)-FIND("""";N4)-1);"" - "")" It works just fine for me. Also there is  no need for 2 lines. you can do this in 1 line. wsFinal.Range("P2:P" & lastRowRange).Formula = "=IFERROR(MID(N4;FIND("""";N4)+1;LEN(N4)-FIND("""";N4)-1);"" - "")"

@SiddharthRout
"=IFERROR(MID(N4;FIND("""";N4)+1;LEN(N4)-FIND("""";N4)-1);"" - "")" resolves to =IFERROR(MID(N4,FIND("",N4)+1,LEN(N4)-FIND("",N4)-1)," - ").  The OP wanted =IFERROR(MID(M5,FIND("""",M5)+1,LEN(M5)-FIND("""",M5)-1),"-")

Should be:  "=IFERROR(MID(M4,FIND("""""""",M4)+1,LEN(M4)-FIND("""""""",M4)-1),""-"")"

@Michal. Yes I am aware and I was typing my answer when you posted. Also it doesn't matter if it is "M" or "N" :) The formula will work.

Your 1st formula refers to Column M and the formula in the VBA code refers to Column N. I am taking Column N for my example. Feel free to change N to M.
There is nothing wrong with your formula. It works fine for me. Also you do not need to use .Autofill to fill the range. You can enter the formula in the entire range in one go. Here is an example.
In my PC, the separator is , instead of ; so I have used that.
Option Explicit

Sub Sample()
    Dim sFormula As String
    'sFormula = "=IFERROR(MID(N4;FIND("""";N4)+1;LEN(N4)-FIND("""";N4)-1);"" - "")"
    sFormula = "=IFERROR(MID(N4,FIND("""",N4)+1,LEN(N4)-FIND("""",N4)-1),"" - "")"
    
    Dim lastRowRange As Long: lastRowRange = 5 '<~~ For testing purpose
    
    Dim wsFinal As Worksheet
    Set wsFinal = Sheet1 '<~~ For testing purpose
    
    wsFinal.Range("P2:P" & lastRowRange).Formula = sFormula
End Sub

Output


The formula needs to adjusted 1 column over, in the worksheet, just drag it to get the correct formulal

Now that we have the correct formula in

=IFERROR(MID(N4,FIND("""",N4)+1,LEN(N4)-FIND("""",N4)-1),"-")


Now we have the correct formula in the cell.  Don't try convert it to VBA manually.
• 34 is the CHR code for a double quote
•String(1, 34) = 1 double quote
•String(2, 34) = 2 double quotes
• Replace(ActiveCell.Formula, String(1,34), String(2,34)) will replace all the double quotes in the ActiveCell's Formula with 2 Double Quotes.
Knowing this, we can use the Immediate Window to build our formula

We can even set variables and test code in the Immediate Window.

Answer for my system
wsFinal.Range("P2:P" & lastRowRange).Formula = _
    "=IFERROR(MID(N4,FIND("""""""",N4)+1,LEN(N4)-FIND("""""""",N4)-1),""-"")"


### European version
We can also convert the version from comma separated to semi-colon separated using the **Immediate Window**.

wsFinal.Range("P2:P" & lastRowRange).Formula = _
    "=IFERROR(MID(N4;FIND("""";N4)+1;LEN(N4)-FIND("""";N4)-1);"-")"


FunThomas pointed out that VBA automatically converts the formula to the local delimiter.

Note: Excel Formulas in VBA are always in US-English format (except when you use them in conditional formatting), no need to replace comma with semicolon. If you insist to use local formulas, you can use .FormulaLocal, but in that case you need to use also the language-dependent formula names (eg WENNFEHLER instead of IFERROR in german).

@FunThomas I had a german client that I ran into issues because of the formulas that I wrote had comma separated parameters.   It has to do with the Windows List Separator setting:  Comma or Semicolon in an Excel formula

When you write a formula in VBA, it's always the US-english version and it's using comma as separator. The Excel-engine will translate the local formula you see in an, let's say, german Excel into the US-version (and vice versa) when you use it in VBA. Lot's of questions here on SO about that. Exceptions are formulas in data validation and in conditional formatting.

@FunThomas, you are correct.  I changed the delimiter and tested it.  Thanks!

I don't think I've ever had to do it this way:
Range("P2").Formula = "=IFERROR(MID(M4,FIND(""" & Chr(34) & Chr(34) & _
""",M4)+1,LEN(M4)-FIND(""" & Chr(34) & Chr(34) & """,M4)-1),""-"")"

Actually, the following could be more readable:
Dim strDitto As String
strDitto = Chr(34) & Chr(34)

Range("P2").Formula = "=IFERROR(MID(M4,FIND(""" & strDitto & _
""",M4)+1,LEN(M4)-FIND(""" & strDitto & """,M4)-1),""-"")"


Write Formula With VBA

You must double the double-quotes.
If you want to use .Formula, you must replace the semicolons with (the default) commas.

Compact
Sub AutoFillGenericFormulaCompact()
    
    Const FIRST_CELL_ADDRESS As String = "N2"
    Const FORMULA_COLUMN As String = "P"
    ' The string from the character after the first double-quote
    ' to the penultimate character.
    Const GENERIC_FORMULA As String = "" _
        & "=IFERROR(MID(XXX,FIND("""""""",XXX)+1," _
        & "LEN(XXX)-FIND("""""""",XXX)-1),""-"")"
    Const CELL_REPLACEMENT As String = "XXX"
    'Debug.Print GENERIC_FORMULA
    
    With wsFinal.Range(FIRST_CELL_ADDRESS)
        Dim RowsCount As Long: RowsCount = wsFinal _
            .Cells(wsFinal.Rows.Count, .Column).End(xlUp).Row - .Row + 1
        If RowsCount < 1 Then Exit Sub ' no data
        .Resize(RowsCount).EntireRow.Columns(FORMULA_COLUMN).Formula = _
            Replace(GENERIC_FORMULA, CELL_REPLACEMENT, FIRST_CELL_ADDRESS)
    End With

End Sub

Argumented

To not clutter your code, you could write ...

Sub AutoFillGenericFormula( _
        ByVal ws As Worksheet, _
        ByVal FirstCellAddress As String, _
        ByVal FormulaColumn As String, _
        ByVal GenericFormula As String, _
        Optional ByVal CellReplacement As String = "XXX")
    
    With ws.Range(FirstCellAddress)
        Dim RowsCount As Long: RowsCount = ws _
            .Cells(ws.Rows.Count, .Column).End(xlUp).Row - .Row + 1
        If RowsCount < 1 Then Exit Sub ' no data
        .Resize(RowsCount).EntireRow.Columns(FormulaColumn).Formula = _
            Replace(GENERIC_FORMULA, CellReplacement, FirstCellAddress)
    End With
    
End Sub


... and utilize it in your sub with the following:

Sub AutFillGenericFormulaTEST()
    Const GENERIC_FORMULA As String = "" _
        & "=IFERROR(MID(XXX,FIND("""""""",XXX)+1," _
        & "LEN(XXX)-FIND("""""""",XXX)-1),""-"")"

    AutoFillGenericFormula wsFinal, "N2", "P", GENERIC_FORMULA

End Sub

Existing Formula

Similarly, if the formula already exists in the first cell (P2), you could simplify with the following trio:

Sub AutoFillFormulaCompact()
    
    Const FIRST_CELL_ADDRESS As String = "N2"
    Const FORMULA_COLUMN As String = "P"
    
    With wsFinal.Range(FIRST_CELL_ADDRESS)
        Dim RowsCount As Long: RowsCount = wsFinal _
            .Cells(wsFinal.Rows.Count, .Column).End(xlUp).Row - .Row + 1
        If RowsCount < 1 Then Exit Sub ' no data
        .Resize(RowsCount).EntireRow.Columns(FORMULA_COLUMN) _
            .Formula = .Cells(1).Formula
    End With
    
End Sub

Sub AutoFillFormula( _
        ByVal ws As Worksheet, _
        ByVal FirstCellAddress As String, _
        ByVal FormulaColumn As String)
    
    With ws.Range(FirstCellAddress)
        Dim RowsCount As Long: RowsCount = ws _
            .Cells(ws.Rows.Count, .Column).End(xlUp).Row - .Row + 1
        If RowsCount < 1 Then Exit Sub ' no data
        .Resize(RowsCount).EntireRow.Columns(FormulaColumn) _
            .Formula = .Cells(1).Formula
    End With
    
End Sub

Sub AutFillFormulaTEST()
    AutoFillFormula wsFinal, "N2", "P"
End Sub

